# MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted, Simple NFT Miniting Dapp

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, javascript, ethers.js

I'm building a simple NFT minting Dapp for fundraising. I first deployed contracts on Polygon testnet and then on Ethereum testnet goerli. While integrating[image], my front-end with my smart contracts using Ethers.js, I'm getting the same errors. Did my research and also tried some solutions available but still got the same errors.

Here is the full repo: https://github.com/DevABDee/WagmiPakistan
You can use live-Server to run the application, I'm using simple `HTML`

My hardhat.config.js:

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });

POLYGON_TESTNET_URL = process.env.POLYGON_TESTNET_URL;
GOERLI_TESTNET_URL = process.env.GOERLI_TESTNET_URL;
PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;

module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.7",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },
  networks: {
    matic: {
      url: POLYGON_TESTNET_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      gas: 2100000,
      gasPrice: 8000000000
    },
    goerli: {
      url: GOERLI_TESTNET_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      gas: 2100000,
      gasPrice: 8000000000
    }
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  }
};
```

Index.js:

```js
import { ethers } from "https://cdn-cors.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.5.4.esm.min.js";
import {contractAddress, contractAbi} from  "./constants.js";

const mintBronze = document.getElementById('MintBronze');
const mintSteel = document.getElementById('MintSteel');
const mintGold = document.getElementById('MintGold');
const mintDiamond = document.getElementById('MintDiamond');
const mintPlatinum = document.getElementById('MintPlatinum');

mintBronze.onclick = MintBronze;
mintSteel.onclick = MintSteel;
mintGold.onclick = MintGold;
mintDiamond.onclick = MintDiamond;
mintPlatinum.onclick = MintPlatinum;

async function connect() {

    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undifined') {
        await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
        console.log("Connected");
    } else {
        console.log("Get A Metamask Wallet");
    }

}

connect();

let provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
let signer = provider.getSigner();
let wagmiPakistanContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, signer)


async function MintBronze() {
    const mintBronze = wagmiPakistanContract.mintBronze();
    const Bronze = await mintBronze;
    console.log(`${Bronze} Minted`);
}
async function MintSteel() {
    const mintSteel = wagmiPakistanContract.mintSteel();
    const Steel = await mintSteel;
    console.log(`${Steel} Minted`);
}
async function MintGold() {
    const mintGold = wagmiPakistanContract.mintGold();
    const Gold = await mintGold;
    console.log(`${Gold} Minted`);
}
async function MintDiamond() {
    const mintDiamond = wagmiPakistanContract.mintDiamond();
    const Diamond = await mintDiamond;
    console.log(`${Diamond} Minted`);
}
async function MintPlatinum() {
    const mintPlatinum = wagmiPakistanContract.mintPlatinum();
    const Platinum = await mintPlatinum;
    console.log(`${Platinum} Minted`);
}
```

Pls help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if the contract address you are deploying to the testnet is correct. If it is, check if the method you're calling is correct. Finally, check if the parameters in the function call are correct.

Comment: yes I was putting the params wrong. Thanks